# Determine whether two complex numbers are equal

Tags: python, numpy

The following code causes the print statements to be executed:

```
import numpy as np
import math

foo = np.array([1/math.sqrt(2), 1/math.sqrt(2)], dtype=np.complex_)

total = complex(0, 0)
one = complex(1, 0)
for f in foo:
   total = total + pow(np.abs(f), 2)
   if(total != one):
      print str(total) + " vs " + str(one)
      print "NOT EQUAL"
```

However, my input of `[1/math.sqrt(2), 1/math.sqrt(2)]` results in the `total` being `one`:

```
(1+0j) vs (1+0j) NOT EQUAL
```

Is it something to do with mixing NumPy with Python's complex type?

Comment: Try `repr(total)` instead of `str(total)`

Comment: Most probably this is an issue of comparing floating point numbers - since the complex type is just the combination of two floating point numbers. Check e.g. this little guide: http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/ on how to compare floating point numbers. Similarly, try `2 == sqrt(2)*sqrt(2)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, the same considerations as for real numbers are applicable: never assume they can be equal, but rather close enough:

```
eps = 0.000001
if abs(a - b) < eps:
    print "Equal"
```

Comment: You may also use `np.isclose` or for arrays `np.allclose`

Comment: Never *assume*, but sometimes it's possible to *know*. Floating equality isn't evil as long as you know where errors can arise. For example, floating point is exact on the integrals up to something like 2**53 IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

When using floating point numbers it is important to keep in mind that working with these numbers is never accurate and thus computations are every time subject to rounding errors. This is caused *by the design of [floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)* and currently the most practicable way to do high arbitrary precision mathematics on computers with limited resources. You can't compute exactly using floats (means you have practically no alternative), as your numbers have to be cut off somewhere to fit in a reasonable amount of memory (in most cases at maximum 64 bits), this cut-off is done by rounding it (see below for an example).

To deal correctly with these shortcomings you should never compare to floats for equality, but for closeness. Numpy provides 2 functions for that: [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) for comparison of single values (or a item-wise comparison for arrays) and [`np.allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) for whole arrays. The latter is a `np.all(np.isclose(a, b))`, so you get a single value for an array.

```
>>> np.isclose(np.float32('1.000001'), np.float32('0.999999'))
True
```

But sometimes the rounding is very practicable and matches with our [analytical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis) expectation, see for example:

```
>>> np.float(1) == np.square(np.sqrt(1))
True
```

After squaring the value will be reduced in size to fit in the given memory, so in this case it's rounded to what we would expect.

These two functions have built-in absolute and relative tolerances (you can also give then as parameter) that are use to compare two values. By default they are `rtol=1e-05` and `atol=1e-08`.

---

Also, don't mix different packages with their types. If you use Numpy, use Numpy-Types and Numpy-Functions. This will also reduce your rounding errors.

Btw: Rounding errors have even more impact when working with numbers which differ in their exponent widely.

Comment: As I replied to bereal, it's important to note that a floating point *number* is exact; it's merely that *some* floating point *operations* aren't. For example, `16.0 ** 0.5` will always give an exact answer of `4.0`, but something like `10 ** 0.5` obviously has to be rounded. Typically (but not always), if the inputs and output are exactly representably, the calculation will be exact.

Comment: Yes, thanks. the number is always exact, the operation has to round the numbers and is thus inaccurate. I clarified that in my answer.

Comment: @Veedrac Well `10**0.5` is kind of obvious since the number is irrational. As far as I understand, it's not only about precision, but about the fundamental gap between decimal and binary systems, due to which numbers like `0.1` can't have a finite binary representation, the same way as `1/3` can't have a finite decimal representation. For that reason, for example, `1.1 + 2.2 == 3.3` turns out `False`, even though the operation is trivial and exponents are the same.

Comment: @bereal That's one of the common causes, but hardly the only one. One thing that stumped me recently was expecting `Ax + B(1-x)` to always be between `A` and `B` for `0≤x≤1`, given that `A` and `B` were exact. I had to rewrite it to `B + (A-B)x`.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**

The proper way of comparing either floats or complex numbers is:

```py
def isclose(a, b, rtol=1e-5, atol=1e-8):
    return abs(a-b) < atol + rtol * abs(b)
```

which is essentially what `np.isclose()` does under the hood, with `np.isclose()` being preferable as it takes care about infinities, not-a-numbers, etc.

**Details:**

The particular case from the question is not specific to complex numbers. If you replace

```py
total = complex(0, 0)
one = complex(1, 0)
```

with its floating point equivalent

```
total = 0
one = 1
```

you'll get exactly the same result:

```
0.4999999999999999 vs 1
NOT EQUAL
0.9999999999999998 vs 1
NOT EQUAL
```

The criterion `abs(a-b) < epsilon` suggested by @bereal works in some cases, but if you look at the error in different scales:

```
>>> np.sqrt(1.234)**2-1.234
2.220446049250313e-16
>>> np.sqrt(12.34)**2-12.34
1.7763568394002505e-15
>>> np.sqrt(123.4)**2-123.4
-1.4210854715202004e-14
```

you'll see that it linearly increases for large numbers (which is not really surprising as floating point only keeps 15 decimal digits for float64), so it would be more reasonable to use a relative difference rather than the absolute one:

```
abs(a-b)/a < epsilon
```

It resolves an issue of the increasing error, but even a quick glance reveals problems with `a==0`. And no matter which flavor you prefer:
  • `abs(a-b)/max(a,b)` (used in `math.isclose()`),
  • `abs(a-b)/(a+b)`
or what not, they all have the same problem: they fail when `a` and/or `b` is zero.

To address this issue, it is a common practice to have two 'epsilons': an absolute epsilon (aka `atol`, absolute tolerance) for comparing with zero and a relative one (aka `rtol`, relative tolerance) for comparing with anything else.

As a bottomline:
  • `np.isclose()` does `abs(a-b) <= atol + rtol * abs(b)`
  • `math.isclose()` does `abs(a-b) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol)`

The `math` version is more symmetric, but the `numpy` version is faster.